# Set row color to specific rows

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am working on Angular4 project and am using ngx-datatable so .html file looks like

`<ngx-datatable>
    <ngx-datatable-column>
        <ng-template> ...
         {{row.value}}`

What I want to achieve is to check for value, whether with `*ngIf` or inside typescript for value, and if value > 100 set ROW background to red, else it should be white as it is.

How to achieve that? 
Thanks for help

Comment: Could you add more code about the ngx-datatable and the array that you are iterating?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can exchange CSS classes conditionally as follows:

```
<ng-template [ngClass]="{red: row.value >= 100, white: row.value < 100}">
```

Of course you have to define the CSS-styles behind both classes red and white in your CSS-file.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the row..

```
[style.background-color]='row.value >= 100 ? "red":"" '
```